# Best way to approach sensor fusion

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter, weighted-regression, sensor-data

I'm fusing acceleration data from an accelerometer and the derived acceleration from a distance sensor to learn about sensor fusion. The derived acceleration (2nd derivative) from the distance sensor was fairly noisy. I used a moving average filter to clean up the data and it seems to match the accelerometer data fairly well.

[image: Before FilteringBlue is accelerometer data, green is acceleration data derived from the distance sensor]

[image: After FilteringBlue is acceleration data, green is acceleration data derived from distance sensor with averaging filter implemented]

I was going to use a weighted average of the two measurements to combine the sensor data to provide a more accurate (hopefully) acceleration as described by this [link](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/hpa4u5hmxk599/hs3g1ig289y5r6).

I've got a few basic questions:

- Is sensor fusion even worth it in this case? It looks like the accelerometer is generally more accurate - so would I just be decreasing the accuracy by adding the measurements from the distance sensor?
- Is a weighted average the right algorithm to be using in the first place?

Thanks!